# C# Record Types compiles with an extra reference when "cloning" record

Tags: c#, decompiler, c#-9.0, c#-record-type

I am experimenting a bit with C# `record` types and was wondering why the compiler behaves as it does, with the following example.

My code looks like this

```
public class C {
    public void M() {
        Point p1 = new Point(3, 3);
        Point p2 = p1 with { Y = 4 };
    }
}

record Point(int X,int Y);
```

Looking at Sharplab.io, its seems like the compiler adds on an extra reference for p2.

```
public void M()
{
    Point point = new Point(3, 3);
    Point point2 = point.<Clone>$();
    point2.Y = 4;
    Point point3 = point2;
}
```

(It only does this when I mutate the record (non destructively, of course)).

Why is that?

Comment: Only in debug mode. In `Release` it's `new Point(3, 3).<Clone>$().Y = 4;`

Comment: And if you check the IL in Debug, you'll see the `p2` is actually the clone generated and modified. Only one variable is set at the end with `stloc.1`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Hmmm. That's interesting. Do you know why it would do it in debug mode?

Comment: It is technically allways there, but when you build in non debug the compiler in-lines unrefrenced intermediate variables to increase speed

Comment: They might have done this so you could set a breakpoint on the with expression.  That however did not work out in the current debug engine.

Answer (score 0):

This code doesn't create an additional object instance or a new reference. A variable isn't a storage location, it's essentially a name by which we refer to an object instance.

`with` creates a clone of the original object and modifies some of its values. That's what this code shows. `point3` isn't a new reference. This part :

```
 p1 with { Y = 4 }
```

is translated to

```
Point point2 = point.<Clone>$();
point2.Y = 4;
```

The result of that operation is finally stored in the target variable with :

```
Point point3 = point2;
```

Record types are reference types, so the final assignment doesn't result in copies or allocations. .NET isn't reference-counted, so the variable assignment  doesn't cost either.

**Exception safety**

Even if there was a different way to write such code (there isn't), it's *safer* to construct the full object separately and then assign it to its final location. This means that should something go wrong we can just discard the new instance than try to revert any changes made to the half-completed object.

Comment: You haven't really answered the question. Forget the fact that it doesn't cost anything. What is the point of it?

Comment: I actually answered that. `p1 with { Y = 4 }` creates a new instance and then modifies its properties. That's what `p2` is - the new copy. The modified instance is then stored in the variable you specified. `p2` and `p3` aren't separate references, `p3` is a different way to refer to the same object. Besides, even in our own code it's *safer* to construct a new instance on the side and only use it after it's fully constructed